# How to override hover background color of Card or CardActionArea using styleOverrides property?

Tags: material-ui

I have component that looks like this,

```
<Card variant="outlined" square>
  <CardActionArea>
    <CardContent>
      <Typography variant="h6">{title}</Typography>
    </CardContent>
  </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

I want to change the hover background color to `indigo[50]`, which is equivalent to `#e8eaf6`. So I override the style like the following,

```
MuiButtonBase: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: indigo[50],
      },
    },
  },
},
```

The above did change the hover color, and the computed styles show the correct color,

[image: computed styles show the correct background color of #e8eaf6]

However, the color looks different than #e8eaf6. It is actually a `#e0e2ed` when inspected using a color picker tool like Eye Dropper. Do you have any idea which CSS rule that is impacting this hover color?

The following code should reproduce this issue (with MUI 5),

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@mui/material/CardActionArea";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import {
  createTheme,
  responsiveFontSizes,
  ThemeProvider
} from "@mui/material/styles";
import { indigo } from "@mui/material/colors";

let theme = createTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
theme = createTheme(theme, {
  components: {
    MuiButtonBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: indigo[50]
            // opacity: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Stack
          justifyContent="center"
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: indigo[50]
          }}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h5">This is indigo[50] (#e8eaf6)</Typography>
          </Toolbar>
          <Card variant="outlined" square>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="h6">
                  Hover me, why the color is different than the above toolbar (#e8eaf6)?
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
          </Card>
        </Stack>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that color pickers like eye dropper will only give you the hex/rgba and not the opacity.  If MUI changes the opacity, the eye dropper app will give you the equivalent hex with an opacity = 1.  Since MUI adjusts the opacity on hover, this is likely the reason you are seeing a different background color hex value.

If you force the opacity to 1 on your style override, I think you'll get the same hex value with the eye dropper.

```js
MuiButtonBase: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: indigo[50],
        opacity: 1,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Adding the opacity to 1 doesn't help. I added a code were you can reproduce the issue.